# vba code to import oversized text file to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text file (.txt) with 1.5M rows of data.  I want to import the data (unformatted) into Excel (2007).  The problem is Excel can only handle 1M rows per tab.  I setup a code to copy the data row by row but it keeps stopping at row 594,139.  I can't work out why.

Can any one please help me with creating VBA code for the following:

- Open the text file and copy data 200,000 rows at a time.
- put the data into Excel (unformatted).
- Get the next 200,000 rows from the text file (etc) and put into excel below previous data.
- when excel reaches row 1,000,000 - setup new tab and continue to put data in Excel.

The above sounds simple but my current Macro doesn't complete.

Any help would really be appreciated,

Below is my original code.  I tried to copy the text in by blocks (200,000 rows) but I then tried line by line.

Sub LargeFileImport()

```
  Dim ResultStr As String
  Dim FileName As String
  Dim FileNum As Integer
  Dim Counter As Double
  FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & InputBox("Please enter the Text File's name, e.g. ifs_ytd_fut") & ".txt"
  If FileName = "" Then End
  FileNum = FreeFile()
  Open FileName For Input As #FileNum
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Dim mypath As String
  mypath = ThisWorkbook.Path
 Workbooks.Add template:=xlWorksheet
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (mypath & "/Extract.xls")
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Counter = 1
  Range("A1").Select
 Do While Seek(FileNum) <= LOF(FileNum)
  Application.StatusBar = "Importing Row " & _
         Counter & " of text file " & FileName
  Line Input #FileNum, ResultStr
  If Left(ResultStr, 1) = "=" Then
         ActiveCell.Value = "'" & ResultStr
  Else
         ActiveCell.Value = ResultStr
  End If
  If ActiveCell.Row = 1000000 Then
       ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
      Else
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      End If
  Counter = Counter + 1
  Loop
  Close
  Application.StatusBar = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
```

CK.

Comment: Post your existing code?

Comment: Well, I see no problems with that ;-)

Comment: Apologies - I updated my original post with the code.  I didn't realise I posted that.  SOrry once again.

Comment: You should probably use either PowerPivot or a database for this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you

```
Sub Tester()

Const LINES_PER_SHEET As Long = 500000
Dim ResultStr As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileNum
Dim Counter As Long, r As Long
Dim wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim arr()
Dim mypath As String

    mypath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
               InputBox("Please enter the Text File's name, e.g. ifs_ytd_fut") & ".txt"
    If FileName = "" Then Exit Sub

    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input As #FileNum

    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(template:=xlWorksheet)
    wbNew.SaveAs (mypath & "/Extract.xls")

    Counter = 0
    r = 0

    ReDim arr(1 To LINES_PER_SHEET, 1 To 1)

    Do While Not EOF(FileNum)

        If Counter Mod 1000 = 0 Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Importing Row " & _
             Counter & " of text file " & FileName
        End If

        Counter = Counter + 1
        r = r + 1
        Line Input #FileNum, ResultStr
        If Left(ResultStr, 1) = "=" Then ResultStr = "'" & ResultStr

        arr(r, 1) = ResultStr
        If r = LINES_PER_SHEET Then
            ArrayToSheet wbNew, arr
            r = 0
        End If
    Loop

    If Counter Mod LINES_PER_SHEET > 0 Then ArrayToSheet wbNew, arr

    Close #FileNum
    Application.StatusBar = False


End Sub

Sub ArrayToSheet(wb As Workbook, ByRef arr)
    Dim r As Long
    r = UBound(arr, 1)
    With wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        .Range("A1").Resize(r, 1).Value = arr
    End With
    ReDim arr(1 To r, 1 To 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim - Thank you very much for your time and effort.  Giving it a try now.  Really appreciate your input.  I hope I get an opportunity to return the favour in the near future.

Comment: Apologies Tim - I have been ill for some time and today is my 1st time logging on in a while.  Yes it worked and thank you again for your support.